# FQL query keeps returning "Invalid API Key", despite working in API Explorer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying the following query:

`SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY rand()`

And it seems to work using the Graph API Explorer tool.  However when I try doing it from my PHP code, I keep getting the error `Invalid API Key`, despite having every single permission possible enabled for it.

Anything I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out some tables require that you specify your application's private key.